# GlobalMemoryStatus function reports invalid available page file in NUnit console run

Tags: c#, nunit, pinvoke, windows-server-2008-r2

I am PInvoking the [`GlobalMemoryStatus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in an NUnit test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern void GlobalMemoryStatus([In, Out] MemoryStatus status);

    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var mem = new MemoryStatus();
        GlobalMemoryStatus(mem);
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0, mem.dwAvailPageFile);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal class MemoryStatus
    {
        public uint dwLength;
        public uint dwMemoryLoad;
        public uint dwTotalPhys;
        public uint dwAvailPhys;
        public uint dwTotalPageFile;
        public uint dwAvailPageFile;
        public uint dwTotalVirtual;
        public uint dwAvailVirtual;
    }
}
```

This test works fine when run inside Visual Studio.

But it fails if executed with `nunit-console.exe`:

```
nunit\nunit-console.exe bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll /framework:net-4.5
```

with this output:

```
PS C:\UnitTestProject1> nunit\nunit-console.exe bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll /framework:net-4.5
NUnit-Console version 2.6.4.14350
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.5466 ( Net 3.5 )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: net-4.5
.F
Tests run: 1, Errors: 0, Failures: 1, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 0.1470761 seconds
  Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0

Errors and Failures:
1) Test Failure : UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1
     Expected: not 0
  But was:  0
```

If I use `MSTest` it works fine:

```
mstest /testcontainer:bin/debug/unittestproject1.dll
```

with this output:

```
C:\UnitTestProject1>mstest /testcontainer:bin/debug/unittestproject1.dll
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 11.0.61030.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading bin/debug/unittestproject1.dll...
Starting execution...

Results               Top Level Tests
-------               ---------------
Passed                UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1
1/1 test(s) Passed

Summary
-------
Test Run Completed.
  Passed  1
  ---------
  Total   1
Results file:  C:\UnitTestProject1\TestResults\ddimitrov_BPCANALYTICS01 2015-04-02 14_09_16.trx
Test Settings: Default Test Settings
```

I am running the test on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard x64 machine with 6GB of RAM. The same `nunit-console` test works fine on Windows 8.1.

Do you have any idea what I might be doing wrong so that this Win32 function reports incorrect data?

Comment: Your MemoryStatus declaration is wrong, the sizes are IntPtr, not uint.  So a basic diagnostic is that nunit runs in 64-bit mode and mstest in 32-bit mode.  Also, you should be using GlobalMemoryStatusEx() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The struct is [defined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366772.aspx) like so:

```
typedef struct _MEMORYSTATUS {
  DWORD  dwLength;
  DWORD  dwMemoryLoad;
  SIZE_T dwTotalPhys;
  SIZE_T dwAvailPhys;
  SIZE_T dwTotalPageFile;
  SIZE_T dwAvailPageFile;
  SIZE_T dwTotalVirtual;
  SIZE_T dwAvailVirtual;
} MEMORYSTATUS;
```

The `SIZE_T` members are pointer sized which means that your declaration will be incorrect in a 64 bit process. Use `UIntPtr` for these members.

Comment: Alright, this makes total sense. How do I get the corresponding value from the `UIntPtr` then? Would this be correct to use on both x32 and x64: `ulong value = (ulong)mem.dwAvailPageFile;`?

Comment: Yup, that would work fine for both 32 and 64 bit. You should be calling `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` though.

Comment: Thanks @David. I am already calling the `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` function in the first place, but I am using the `GlobalMemoryStatus` function as a fallback because the code I am writing needs to work on some pretty exotic environments such as .NET Compact Framework for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comment from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366772(v=vs.85).aspx):

> On computers with more than 4 GB of memory, the MEMORYSTATUS structure can return incorrect information, reporting a value of –1 to indicate an overflow. If your application is at risk for this behavior, use the GlobalMemoryStatusEx function instead of the GlobalMemoryStatus function.